# Iterators.any in Guava library

Tags: java, collections, iterator, guava

Guava Iterators.any method documentation mentioned that this call will return one or more elements satisfy the predicate.Does it mean that the predicate run for **all the elements** in the iterator even though the first element satisfied the condition ?

**Class Iterators**

"Returns true if one or more elements returned by iterator satisfy the given predicate."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Iterators.any` source:

```
647 public static <T> boolean any(
648       Iterator<T> iterator, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
649     checkNotNull(predicate);
650     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
651       T element = iterator.next();
652       if (predicate.apply(element)) {
653         return true;
654       }
655     }
656     return false;
657 }
```

It's a normal Iterator.

It will iterate until founds an element which is OK for the predicate. When it finish because the `return true;` it means **at least** one element satisfied the condition but it could happen that others too satisfied the condition without the need to check. (that's the `Returns true if one or more` part)

But if none satisfied the condition it will return false since noone stopped the iterator.